# Counting how often each id occurs in xml at each date with php

Tags: php, xml, count

I'm just trying to wrap my head around it, but I feel lost.
I have an xml with this kind of structure:

```
<Logs>
    <Log>
        <AppID>12345</AppID>
        <Module>String</Module>
        <Info>String</Info>
        <Date>Datetime</Date>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        ...
    </Log>
</Logs>
```

What I need is a kind of output, how often on each day an AppID was logged.
Something like:

```
20016-06-01: 12345: 5 times, 12557: 2 times
20016-06-02: 12345: 3 times, 18949: 1 times
```

I already use simple_xml to load the xml file and go through it with:

```
foreach ($loadedxml->Log as $error){...}
```

Comment: so exactly what did you try? the foreach is nice and all, but that's the least/simplest part of the problem.

Comment: I created an array wth all the occuring dates (with !in_array) - but now I don't know to get the count of each AppID for each date and refer it to the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With php, hashtables are often the answer :

```
$res = array();
foreach ($loadedxml->Logs->Log as $curLog)
{
   if (!isset($res[(String)$curLog->Date]))
      $res[(String)$curLog->Date] = array();

   $lstLogDate = &$res[(String)$curLog->Date];
   if (!isset($lstLogDate[(String)$curLog->AppID])
      $lstLogDate[(String)$curLog->AppID] = 0;

   $lstLogDate[(String)$curLog->AppID]++;
}
```

This code create an hashtable with all dates as key and for each entries, there is a list fill with id as key and number occurs as value.
Next code show the result :

```
foreach ($res as $dateValue => $lstId)
{
   echo $dateValue . ": ";

   foreach ($lstId as $id => $countId)
     echo $id . ": " . $countId . "times";

   echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: You must cast  simplexml object to string and can do one check

Comment: True ... sorry forgot :/

Comment: It looks like it should work. Thanks so far. But the last part doesn't seem to generate results for me. I only get the "2016-06-01: " (and so on) but nothing past the ":"

Comment: I'm not sure cause it's php but I probably forgot reference. I edit in code

Comment: Now I know what was missing: $lstLogDate = &$res[$newformat]; The & needed to be there, since it wasn't keeping the index. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Classic example of the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) for grouping in XSLT 1.0. As information, XSLT (whose script is a well-formed XML document) is a special-purpose language used to transform XML files. PHP like most general purpose languages maintains an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Below XSLT script runs `<xsl:key>` on the concatenation of the `<AppID>` and `<Date>` and then counts distinct group values. In fact, XSLT can output your string lines without a single `for` loop!

**XML** Input *(for reproducible example)*

```
<Logs>
    <Log>
        <AppID>12345</AppID>
        <Module>Falcon</Module>
        <Info>Avengers Assemble</Info>
        <Date>2016-06-01</Date>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        <AppID>12345</AppID>
        <Module>Captain America</Module>
        <Info>Avengers Assemble</Info>
        <Date>2016-06-01</Date>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        <AppID>12557</AppID>
        <Module>Black Widow</Module>
        <Info>Avengers Assemble</Info>
        <Date>2016-06-01</Date>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        <AppID>12345</AppID>
        <Module>Iron Man</Module>
        <Info>Avengers Assemble</Info>
        <Date>2016-06-02</Date>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        <AppID>12557</AppID>
        <Module>Hulk</Module>
        <Info>Avengers Assemble</Info>
        <Date>2016-06-02</Date>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        <AppID>12557</AppID>
        <Module>Blackhawk</Module>
        <Info>Avengers Assemble</Info>
        <Date>2016-06-01</Date>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        <AppID>12345</AppID>
        <Module>Thor</Module>
        <Info>Avengers Assemble</Info>
        <Date>2016-06-01</Date>
    </Log>
</Logs>
```

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl document to be loaded below)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="appkey" match="Log" use="concat(AppID, Date)" />

  <xsl:template match="Logs">        
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Log[generate-id() = 
                                       generate-id(key('appkey',concat(AppID, Date))[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="concat(Date, AppID)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>        
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Log[generate-id() = 
                           generate-id(key('appkey',concat(AppID, Date))[1])]">    
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(Date, ': ', AppID, ' ', 
                            count(. | key('appkey', concat(AppID, Date))), ' times')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** Script

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
$xmlfile = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xmlfile->load('Input.xml');

$xslfile = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xslfile->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// TRANSFORM XML with XSLT
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslfile); 
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($xmlfile);

// ECHO OUTPUT STRING
echo $newXml;

# 2016-06-01: 12345 3 times
# 2016-06-01: 12557 2 times
# 2016-06-02: 12345 1 times
# 2016-06-02: 12557 1 times
```